# Aframe glb environment map reflections artifacts

Tags: aframe

I'm using a component to set up reflections on a glb model using an equirectangular texture in AFRAME.

The code is the following :

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-orbit-controls@1.3.0/dist/aframe-orbit-controls.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="components.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a-scene
        light="defaultLightsEnabled: true"
        renderer="antialias: true; colorManagement: true;">
        <a-assets>
            <img id="sky" src="env.jpg">
            <a-asset-item id="model" src="./helmet.glb"></a-asset-item>
        </a-assets>
        <a-entity
            id="camera"
            camera="near: 0.1; far: 1000"
            orbit-controls="
            target: 0 0 0;
            zoomSpeed: 3;
            minDistance: 0;
            maxDistance: 100;
            initialPosition: 5 2 5;
            autoRotate: true;
            autoRotateSpeed: 0.02;
            enablePan: true">
        </a-entity>
        <a-entity gltf-model="#model" envmap></a-entity>
        <a-sky src="#sky"></a-sky>
    </a-scene>
  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("envmap", {
  init: function() {
    let mesh = this.el.getObject3D("mesh");
    if (mesh) {
      loadEnvMap(scene.renderer, this.el);
    } else {
      this.el.addEventListener("model-loaded", () => {
        loadEnvMap(this.el.sceneEl.renderer, this.el);
      });
    }
  }
});

function loadEnvMap(renderer, entity) {
  let targetCube = new THREE.WebGLCubeRenderTarget(1024, { generateMipmaps: true, minFilter: THREE.LinearMipmapLinearFilter });
  renderer.toneMapping = THREE.ACESFilmicToneMapping;
  renderer.toneMappingExposure = 1;
  renderer.outputEncoding = THREE.sRGBEncoding;

  let mesh = entity.getObject3D("mesh");
  let texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load(
    "./env.jpg",
    function() {
      let cubeTex = targetCube.fromEquirectangularTexture(renderer, texture);
      mesh.traverse(function(el) {
        if (el.material) {
          el.material.envMap = cubeTex.texture;
          el.material.envMap.intensity = 1;
          el.material.needsUpdate = true;
        }
      });
    });
}
```

The texture I use for the environment map is this one.
[image: Environment map]

And the glb model is this one : https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/damaged-helmet-source-glb-fc8449ca5f3f490d83ba6a7ae087ff55

I get the following results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9TO9.jpg

As you can see, the rendering on the side of the helmet is very pixelated and I don't really know why. The env.jpg file I have has a resolution of 4096x2048.

Any idea on how I could fix this ?

Comment: Is it PC / macOS / mobile? Tried it [out](https://jsfiddle.net/3f2cpat1/1/) and i don't get the shimmering https://imgur.com/a/avulgQI

Comment: This happens on PC on 3 different browsers (Chrome, Brave, Edge). Just tried it on my phone (iOS) and the shimmering disappears, that's weird.

Comment: is it also shimmering in my fiddle? Also does it happen only when the `envMap` is applied?

Comment: Same thing for me in your fiddle yeah, and it does only happen when envMap is added. Might be a problem with my graphics card?